# What does the notation $f^{(iv)}$ mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I want to solve the following exercise:

Does there exist a nonzero function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{(iv)}(t) + f(t) = 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow + \infty} f(t) = \lim_{t \rightarrow + \infty}f'(t) = 0$?

but I don't understand what is meant with $f^{(iv)}$ here. They don't say what $i$ or $v$ are anywhere.

Comment: It is the fourth derivative of $f$.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I was used to writing $f^{(4)}$ and just use numbers for any derivative after 3.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_numerals

Comment: I am aware of latin numerals. I just haven't seen them be used for derivatives like this.

Comment: Actually, the primes of $f'$, $f''$ and $f'''$ are also roman numerals, introduced by Lagrange (IIRC).